# Is it possible to refer to component's template as to a file in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, templates, flask, vuejs2

I'm developing a SPA using Flask and Vuejs. I found Vuejs very lightweight framework so I've chosen it. But now I'm facing a problem - my SPA has several pages, or views that can replace each other when different links are clicked. I found the Vue components could do that.

Really, I can use

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

and Vue router works perfectly.

But the problem is with components. Usually in examples I see something like that:

```
const User = {
  template: '<div>User</div>'
}
```

But it probably would work for very small apps. In my case, my templates are very big and complicated html layout so I want them to be separated from the code. Ideally it would look like:

```
const User = {
  templatePath: 'user.html'
}
```

but I can't figure out how to implement it. Previously I worked with AngularJS and it was very convenient and easy to gain it but not now.

**Note: I shouldn't use Node.js, webpack or anything else besides Python and JavaScript.**

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't tell `vuejs` to load the template at runtime with properties like `templateUrl`.

VueJS [doc](https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/) says

> Think in components, not templates

So think in components and split your large templates/logics into smaller components, it should solve the issue.

If you are still not convinced, you can do one thing.

Separate js and css parts of your component into respective files. Now your component will have only html and the js/css file tags. Something like below,

```
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
  <div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: "Think in components, not templates" doesn't mean that I *must* put everything into one file. I still can think in components but separate layout and code for better readability. I don't understand why they impose to implement only one design pattern whereas others may not be worse but even better.